# Google Authenticator iOS app - Restoring tokens

Tags: ios

I use [Google Authenticator](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-authenticator/id388497605) app on my iPhone as 2-Factor-Authentication agent. I have added tokes for numerous Web applications that I routinely log into via various devices.

Now, I wish to reset my iPhone and set it up again as a new device. How do I easily restore the tokens for the various services that are currently added in Google Authenticator?

I never backup my iPhone on iCloud/iTunes. Hence, I am not looking to backup and restore from a backup.

I found [this](https://www.brianckeegan.com/2016/09/how-to-transfer-googles-2-factor-authentication-to-a-new-iphone/) tutorial which guides with migrating tokes onto the app running on a **separate** phone. I just have a **single iPhone**, which I am looking to reset and re-install the authenticator app onto.